# How to decode binary data from a rosbag?

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to echo the topics of a bag file, i get a message :  `data: !!binary | ChQJpiM5J7b11UESB2dhdGV3YXkYSRI7GAEt0YmNPjUAAAAARQAAAABNAAAAAF0AAAAAqAEAsAEA uAEAygEUCaYjOSe29dVBEgdjaGFzc2lzGAcamgEKGwl+jANaaLcaQRG3Y7kbwu1QQRlNc4QFq/qd vxIkCQAAAAAAAAAAEQAAAAAAAAAAGbZX/zsVBNw/IYPT7lNnxew/GhsJlaAsEDqx0T8R+pqtiJCs kzwZBQSdL5XVZj8iGwmW/f98qKacPxHERbyH1aKhvBlzAOArHy9+vyobCfeLggMmjbI8ER2XZG1t Jzg/GfBTn4g5Yn08IQAAAAAAABxA`

This data seems to be binary encoded. The message type of this topic is `string`. How can i read this data ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291176/how-to-decode-binary-data-from-a-rosbag-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-15**:
Can you show us the command you are using to try and echo the topics of a bag file. This doesn't look like anything I've seen from `rostopic echo` before.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-16**:
The command is normal `rostopic echo /pnc/carstatus` but there seems to be a unicode error. It also says : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec cant decode byte 0xe7 in position 1496: ordinal not in range(128)`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
This is most likely a `std_msgs/String` that either:

- contains multibyte characters
- is being abused for transmitting non-character data

It would help if you could show the message definition @aakash_sehgal.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-16**:
@gvdhoorn could you kindly guide me how to do that ? I only have the rosbag file.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-16**:
ran the python script from the command line : `./ message_definition.py Bagname` but it gives the same error : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec cant decode byte 0xe7 in position 1496: ordinal not in range(128)`. Exactly [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/240612/rosbag-unicodedecodeerror/)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
Yes, that's a problem. I don't have time to look into this right now, but it's one of the consequences of <del>most</del> some of ROS Python code not being Unicode aware/safe.

What you could do is open the bag file with a text editor (**don't save it**), then scroll down a bit until you ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
.. come across message definitions.

If you know a bit of text from the definition that would help, as you can then just search for it.

Then carefully copy-paste the def into a new file and save it as a msg def.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
I seem to remember you got this bag / these bags from a colleague. If that is the case, it would be infinitely easier / more convenient to just get the definitions from him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See #q230120.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1